# how to lapply Filter

Tags: r, function, lapply

I use Filter() to remove columns of NAs from data frames.

```
Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), df)
```

I have a list of data frames with columns of NAs that I'd like to run this function on.  I don't understand how to pass these arguments to Filter() when running it in lapply().  The lapply documentation just says '...'.

My best guess is:

```
> lapply(mylist, Filter, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
  object 'f' of mode 'function' was not found
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You need to name arguments, I think, `lapply(mylist, Filter, f = function(x) !all(is.na(x)) )`

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. If you put this as an answer, I'd accept it. 

Where would I learn about details like the need to name the function?   Why do I need to name the function when used as an argument to lapply(), but not when used as an argument to Filter()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you name the arguments explicitly:

```
lapply(mylist, Filter, f = function(x) !all(is.na(x)) )
```

> Where would I learn about details like the need to name the function? Why do I need to name the function when used as an argument to lapply(), but not when used as an argument to Filter()?

Comparing the arguments helps:

```
> args(Filter)
function (f, x) 
> args(lapply)
function (X, FUN, ...)
```

Reading `?lapply`, we see that `lapply(X, FUN, ...)` builds calls like `FUN(X[[i]], ...)`. However, in `Filter(f, x)`, `x` is not in the first position, so we have to name all the arguments that come before it. When we do this, `lapply` knows to build

```
Filter(mylist[[i]], f = function(x) !all(is.na(x)) )
```

which is equivalent to

```
Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), mylist[[i]])
```

For details on how arguments are read, the "Named arguments and defaults" part of the docs may be helpful, in `RShowDoc("R-intro", type = "html")`.